# SignalR getting Disconnected after Invoking methods multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am building a web application using ASP.NET MVC5 and decided to implementing SignalR for notifications.

I decided to also implement it for other real time client-server interactions.

I have a follow button. When clicked it invokes a follow method and sends the ID with it.

```
notificationsHub.server.followAction(requestId);
```

I'm keeping it in the same hub for now, not sure if making it in a separate hub is better.

and I bind another server method when unfollowing.

```
notificationsHub.server.unfollowAction(requestId);
```

It works fine both actions, until it reach about 5-6 clicks then the hub disconnects for no reason.

This is the JavaScript log:

```
[11:30:41 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: Invoking notificationshub.FollowAction
jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82 [11:31:35 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: notificationshub.FollowAction failed to execute. Error: Error: Send failed.
jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82 [11:31:35 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82 [11:31:35 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82 [11:31:35 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82 [11:31:35 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive.
jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82 [11:31:35 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: Clearing hub invocation callbacks with error: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received..
jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82 [11:31:35 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: notificationshub.UnfollowAction failed to execute. Error: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received.
4jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js:82 [11:31:35 GMT+0100 (W. Central Africa Standard Time)] SignalR: notificationshub.FollowAction failed to execute. Error: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Without posting your code how can we possibly help you? We have no context for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the machine I was working needed to have webSockets protocol installed, plus this issue was fixed in the latest signalR release 4 days ago.